# Crystal Reports Code Contracts Conflicts

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, code-contracts

We have a solution built using C# on .NET 4 with Code Contracts. We are hoping to utilise Crystal Reports 13 but are encountering a major problem.

When we attempt to use crystal reports, the following exception occurs:

> Assembly reference not resolved: BusinessObjects.Licensing.KeycodeDecoder, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304.

When Code Contracts runtime checking is disabled (unchecked), this exception does not occur; but code contracts complains the rewriter must be enabled. Unfortunately the codebase is littered with `Contract.Requires<TException>(bool)` calls, which would be a nightmare to change to the if-then-throws style.

Has anyone else encountered this incompatibility? And if so, how did they overcome it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an extra library path to the ContractProperties that points to the directory on your machine containing the missing dll? The rewriter sometimes chases more references than the C# compiler, causing this problem to surface.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not believe the dll in question is actually included in their runtime or SDK. It seems they have a reference to it from one of their other dlls, but do not actually deploy it.

Comment: We have also since stopped using crystal reports, so a newer version of the library may have resolved the issue.

Comment: I see, that's a bummer. As a last resort, you can also add the option -ignoreMetadataErrors to the rewriter options. In case the missing assembly is truly a benign error, this should get you past the rewriter.